# Giving a mechanical penalty to traumatized character

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, homebrew, new-players

I'm currently DMing a campaign with a **time loop**, and to keep players from charging around willy nilly I'm going to implement penalties for getting themselves killed in awful ways. In our last session they made some poor decisions and the group's wizard burned to death, which I feel would be traumatizing enough to affect the character.

I've been trying to figure out a good way to manifest this as a mechanical penalty as my players are new and don't fully play in character. I also don't want to nail them too hard as this will be their first introduction to the fact that dying still affects them.

Ideas I've had:

- Cut back on the character's ability to use fire spells
- Will checks (wisdom saving throws?) to prevent panic when taking fire
  damage
- Disadvantage when making skill checks involving fire

That's about it, I'm just looking for feedback or if anyone has any better ideas on handling this situation. I will definitely be pushing the player to accept their new fear of fire, but I'm afraid they're going to end up ignoring it.

Comment: Have you talked to the players? Have they agreed that their characters would have been traumatized by the experience? Moreover, are they okay with taking a mechanical penalty to make this part of the experience?

Comment: Very interesting question, but you are effectively asking for people's subjective opinions. rpg.se is about questions that can be answered based on fact. You could perhaps rephrase your question to read something like: "Are there any published rules or game mechanics to handle past physical trauma in D&D 5e?"

Answer (score 15):

This is a bit of a frame change, but if you want this to be an interesting and *fun* part of the character and the game, I wouldn't actually use a mechanical penalty for it. Instead, I would take an idea from the game Fate.

They have something called a "Compel", which basically says that if your character is known to be bad at / vulnerable to something and the player decides to roll with it and let it hurt him, they actually get a *bonus* for it.

And D&D actually already has a mechanic that is a little similar... **Inspiration**.

I would ask the player if they'd enjoy roleplaying being traumatized by burning to death, and then tell them that every time they roleplay the trauma in a way that hurts them, they'll get Inspiration to compensate.

It'll be a much more fun experience to actually see the player roleplay being traumatized and look for chances to show how the burning death affected them, then it will be to see the player desperately avoid trying to roleplay being traumatized because it will just hurt them twice (once in their choice of action and once in their mechanical penalty).

Comment: "Ask the player if they'd enjoy roleplaying being traumatized by burning to death" doesn't everyone?

Comment: I think the original poster is asking this because he wants to actually avoid the players from purposefully killing off their PCs as a way to "way more easily" do the Time Loop Adventure. After all, if you know your wizard will just respawn "all fresh", might as well go nuclear throwing everything you have every fight! Or just run down that corridor like a madman instead of checking for traps! Etc. The DM definitely should not give a bonus aka an extra inventive, for players playing in a way that makes sense to them, but "ruin" the adventure/challenge offered.

Comment: My own take on this: making specific penalties according to the way PC died is a hassle. Have a generic rule. More fair. Next game show a sheet to players: "1st Death: You feel a tiny small part of yourself is missing = no penalty. Next deaths: This time a much bigger part goes missing = -2 penalty to all Stats. Ending Time Loop restores all missing self-fragments." Trust me, they'll avoid dying!

Comment: @Pat you should post that as a different answer, it doesn't belong in a comment. Although you'd have to get the question reopened first.